# How do I fix NoneType object is not callable error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, nonetype

I am using Tkinter to move a circle in a canvas a certain amount every second and I have come across the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error in Python. I believe the error is in this block of code:

```py
def move(new_x0, new_y0, new_x1, new_y1):
    new_x0 = new_x0 + speed
    new_y0 = new_y0 + speed
    new_x1 = new_x1 + speed
    new_y1 = new_y1 + speed
    game.canvas.delete("all")
    obj = game.canvas.create_oval(new_x0, new_y0, new_x1, new_y1, fill = color)
    game.canvas.pack()
t = threading.Timer(1.0, move(x0, y0, x1, y1))
t.start()
```

I expected the circle on the canvas to move locations once after 1 second but it just displays the NoneType error.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to show the error. Here it is.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\threading.py", line 1158, in run
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Edit: I solved the NoneType error by doing return obj and then I got int object is not callable, which I solved by doing what ShadowRanger suggested, so my code works now.

Comment: which error? not iterable or not callable?

Comment: show the full traceback

Comment: I'm not sure if it requires parameters, but I believe you intended to wrap the call to `move` in a `lambda`. You're passing the return of `move` to the timer, and it doesn't return anything. I'm not sure if you're wanting `x0` and such to be updated regularly though.

Comment: Your error is here:  `t = threading.Timer(1.0, move(x0, y0, x1, y1))`  The second argument to `Timer` must be a function.  You're passing `None` (the function `move`  has no `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`).  So when it tries to call the function, it ends up trying to call `None`, which of course produces an error.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm not sure how to fix that. Could you possibly write out the code for me.

Comment: You can try something like this:  `t = threading.Timer(1.0, move, [x0, y0, x1, y1])`

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your error is the iterable error, as you claim at the top of your post. Then your code is different from what you posted.

`Timer()` takes iterable arguments (tuples, lists, etc) or keyword arguments as the third argument.

```
move(x0, y0, x1, y1)
```

is `None`, as a function without a return statement implicitly returns `None`. As the error states, `None` is not iterable.

To fix your code, pass in an iterable.

Now let's assume your code is as you posted, and the error is that `None` is not callable. In that case, you must pass a function object (remove the parantheses), and then put `move()`'s arguments as an iterable after (`Timer(1.0, move, [x0, y0, x1, y1]` in this case)

Remember, `Timer()` takes these arguments:

```
Timer(time, function, iterable, kwargs)
```

Edit: you clarified that your error is not the iterable one. Refer to the second example

Comment: The error is that it is not callable, not that it isn't iterable.  Look at the stack trace.  The second argument to `Timer` must be a function, not an iterable.

Comment: You might want to just say how `Timer` must be called in this case: `threading.Timer(1.0, move, (x0, y0, x1, y1))`

Answer (score 0):

`threading.Timer` expects a function to be passed as its second argument.

One simple way to fix this is:

```
t = threading.Timer(1.0, lambda: move(x0, y0, x1, y1))
```